# ¿como realizo una actualización de estado usando jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo que hacer un control de espera, mientras se ejecutan acciones en el backend, que van cambiando el estado de una variable, recuperando, para mostrar, el estado actual de esa variable.

Actualmente tengo esto:

```
var estado='creada';

    while(estado!='enviada'){

            $promesa = $.get(rutaOrden, 
                function (respuesta) 
                    {
                        console.log(respuesta);
                        estado=respuesta["estado"];
                    }
                    );
            $.when($promesa).done(function () {
                console.log("ya");
                console.log(estado);
            });
        }

        });
```

Que, obviamente, no funciona, ¿como hago para periódicamente rellamar al $.get con la ruta y actualizar el estado?

Para resumir, tengo que verificar cada cierto tiempo una variable en la base de datos, y actualizar una barra de progreso.

Comment: Haz probado con setInterval() ;

Comment: Haz eso mismo pero con setInterval donde le pasas un callback ke ejecutaras cada cierto tiempo y cuando el estado sea el ke esperas limpias el intervalo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar el método `setInterval();` para ejecutar cada cierto tiempo la petición, y luego una vez que el estado sea diferente a "enviada" procedemos a eliminar el intervalo utilizando `clearInterval()` para que deje de ejecutar la función.

Un dato importante es que el tiempo de espera que va a tener cada iteración se debe colocar en milisegundos, por lo cual es importante tener en cuenta que 1 segundo equivale a 1000 milisegundos.

```
var estado='creada';

var intervalo = setInterval({
  while(estado!='enviada'){
    $promesa = $.get(rutaOrden, function (respuesta){
        console.log(respuesta);
        estado=respuesta["estado"];
    });

    $.when($promesa).done(function () {
      console.log("ya");
      console.log(estado);
    });
  }

  clearInterval(intervalo);
}, 1000)
```

Ejemplo funcional del `setInterval()` y el `clearInterval()`

```js
var contador = 0;

var intervalo = setInterval(function(){ 
    contador++;
    console.log(contador);
    
    if(contador == 10){
        clearInterval(intervalo);
    }
}, 1000)
```